# SQL Server Set Digit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to set total digit in SQL Server 2008.
For example, I set **5** as the total digit of an ITEM ID. So that if the actual ITEM ID is **205**, it will be converted and shown as **00205**. Thx !

Comment: SQL Server **stores** data - it's not in the business of **nicely formatting** the data..... you should do this in your UI - web or whatever - **NOT** in the database. A value of `205` is just that - 205 - no additional padding 0 or anything make any difference - 205 is 205 is 205 - it's just an INT

Comment: actually I need to use it in a Stored Procedure. I will use the Stored Procedure to export the table into an Excel format, but I need to change the format of the ID first before it's exported. So, it's not possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you should pad the data after it comes back from the database, not in the database itself.

If you must, though:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) AS my_column FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  REPLICATE('0', 5 - len(cast(id as varchar)))+cast(id as varchar) as str_id
from 
  mytable
```

Comment: I also thx you for this. It's working too. Stackoverflow really blessed to have people like you :)